# How to use LoggingSettings to read 'loggingConfiguration' from Web.Config

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code to read the `'loggingConfiguration'` from `web.config` file that is using `EntLib 4.0`

```
Configuration  entLibConfig = 
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration
(@"/Web.config");

LoggingSettings loggingSettings = 
(LoggingSettings)entLibConfig.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName);
```

The `loggingSettings` object is `null` after the `2nd line` executes.

Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap exc = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
exc.ExeConfigFilename = @"Web.exe.config";
Configuration _config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exc,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
LoggingSettings log = _config.GetSection("loggingConfiguration") as LoggingSettings;
```

Try this, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get null returned for `LoggingSettings` is that there is no LoggingSettings  configured in the web.config that you are opening.  This is probably because the path specified is incorrect.

I have a web appliation set up with 2 web.configs: The first in the root and the second in a Config folder.

```
/Root
     web.config
/Root/Config
     web.config
```

The web.config in the Config folder contains the LoggingSettings.  The code to read the LoggingSettings from a page that is not located in the Config folder is:

```
Configuration entLibConfig = 
    WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"~/Config");

LoggingSettings loggingSettings =
    (LoggingSettings)entLibConfig.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName);
```

This should work in the Development Web Server as well as IIS.